# Instantiating multiple view and passing data to each one

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, code-behind

I have a prism app where I am instantiating multiple views in the code-behind of a parent view based on a property in the viewmodel

```
    public I2CNavigatorView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = (I2CNavigatorViewModel) DataContext;

        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.NumberOfI2C; i++)
        {
            var i2CTabItem = new TabItem
            {
                Header = "I2C " + i,
                Content = new I2CView(i)
            };

            NavigatorTabs.Items.Add(i2CTabItem);   
        }
    }
```

and I need to pass the an index to the viewmodel of each child view, so my current solution is to pass the index to the view as a parameter when instantiating the view and setting a variable in the its viewmodel

```
    public I2CView(int currentI2CIndex)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = (I2CViewModel) DataContext;
        viewModel.CurrentI2CIndex = currentI2CIndex;
    }
```

but I am not quite satisfied with the solution as the data flow path is: parent view -> child view ->
child viewmodel, while I need it to be: parent view -> child viewmodel

so I was thinking "Is there a way to pass the data directly to the view model when instantiating the view?"

Please advice,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you do this in `I2CNavigatorView` and not in `I2CNavigatorViewModel`? Surely,  `NavigatorTabs` has a dependency property like `ItemsSource` that you could bind to a property on your view model?

Comment: @Haukinger `NavigatorTabs` is just a tab control, also could you please write an answer to clarify

Comment: My comment was more of a question (as to why you put the logic in the view) than an answer...

Comment: @Haukinger, Oh I am doing it this way from the `I2CNavigatorView`, because I can not instantiate a view from the viewmodel, and if I do it in the way you mentioned I won't be able to pass any parameters to child view or child viewmodel which I really need to do

Comment: `I can not instantiate a view from the viewmodel` - isn't that what a `DataTemplate` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from the view model:

```
internal class I2CNavigatorViewModel
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<I2CViewModel> MyItems { get; }
}

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <I2CView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Then just initialize `MyItems` with the child view models, created with all the parameters you need.

Rant: a `class` doesn't want to have its name start with `I`, because it doesn't like to be mistaken for an `interface`!

Comment: This code outputs a mess, the tabControl must contain a tabItem for each tab(which does not have an `ItemsSource` property), using the code you mentioned just uses the first item in the itemsSource as a header for the tab and put every other item in a stackpanel like view which is not what I want, I want it to add a tab Item for each item in the itemsSource

Comment: are you sure this code works or did I do something wrong

Comment: @technologyworld you're right, `TabControl.ItemTemplate` is for the header of the tab, `TabControl.ContentTemplate` is for the actual tab content.

Comment: Brilliant this actually works, but I have a second issue, I want to have two fixed tabs before the dynamic `I2CView`, so how what should I do?

Comment: What prevents you from putting the view models of the fixed tabs in the collection? Just make it `IReadOnlyCollection<object>` and you're fine. If not, just post a new question :-)

Comment: But why `IReadOnlyCollection` why not a normal `List`?

Comment: @technologyworld Do you want stuff to be added through the property? If you use `List` you're telling everyone "please add your items here, remove some, even clear me!"... if that's what your classes consumers are expected to do, fine, but if you don't want them to change the collection, better expose it read-only...